# OpenCV - unable to use SurfFeatureDetector class

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compile a sample openCV project which uses SURF for image matching.

The code is listed bellow :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
//#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
//#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
//#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void readme();

/** @function main */
int main()
{
/*
if( argc != 3 )
{ readme(); return -1; }

Mat img_1 = imread( argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
Mat img_2 = imread( argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
*/

Mat img_1 = imread("D:\\A.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img_2 = imread("D:\\backImg.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

if( !img_1.data || !img_2.data )
{ std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

//-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
int minHessian = 400;

SurfFeatureDetector detector;

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );

double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

//-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
{ double dist = matches[i].distance;
if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist );
printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist );

//-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist )
//-- PS.- radiusMatch can also be used here.
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
{ if( matches[i].distance < 2*min_dist )
{ good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
}

//-- Draw only "good" matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,
    good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

//-- Show detected matches
imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );

for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
{ printf( "-- Good Match [%d] Keypoint 1: %d  -- Keypoint 2: %d  \n", i,         good_matches[i].queryIdx, good_matches[i].trainIdx ); }

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}

/** @function readme */
void readme()
{ std::cout << " Usage: ./SURF_FlannMatcher <img1> <img2>" << std::endl; }
```

When I try to compile I receive an error for `SurfFeatureDetector` as undeclared identifier. When I right click on it and go to definition it opens it. Should I include something else? It is located in features2d.hpp which is included in cv.h file. Could you please help me with this matter?

Comment: Do you have two versions of OpenCV installed? One of them is 2.4?

Comment: Yes, I have both 2.3.0 and 2.4.2

Comment: si sper ca votezi NU la referendum...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler and editor are confused by the two OpenCV versions installed on your system.

First, make sure that all the settings ( **include** paths in Visual Studio, **lib** path in Visual studio linker settings and **bin** path -probably an environment variable) point to the same version.

Next, make sure to include all the needed headers. In OpenCV 2.4 and above, SURF and SIFT have been moved to `nonfree` module, so you also have to install it. Do not forget that some functions may be moved to `legacy`.

And if you uninstall one version of OpenCV, the editor (which doesn't have all the parsing capabilities of the compiler) will not be confused anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Just add Nonfree module in your header files and it will solve your problem if you are using opencv 2.4.2..

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem 
just include

```
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
```

and solved.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, I do the following steps

- delete different versions of opencv in programfiles.
- check environment variable (only one and right path of opencv version)
- in my project debug folder, I add "cvextern.dll" and "cvextern_gpu.dll" (adding features2d.dll not enough)